# ArgumentError `initialize': wrong number of arguments(8 for 0)

Tags: ruby, constructor, arguments

So I'm very new to Ruby and I'm trying to learn more by converting a python script I'm working on to Ruby.  However, I'm running into a very annoying problem.  Every time I try to run the following code, I get this error:

> player.rb:81:in `initialize': wrong number of arguments(8 for 0)
>   (ArgumentError)   from player.rb:81:in`new'  from player.rb:81:in
>   `'

I'm positive that there are 8 arguments in the initialize method, and I have checked the spelling many times over.  I can't seem to figure out why the interpreter doesn't believe that the constructor doesn't have any arguments.  Could anyone inform me as to what is going wrong below?

```
class Player
    def determineLevel
        @xp_req4lvl = [0, 1000, 2250, 3750, 5500, 7500, 10000, 13000, 16500, 20500, 26000, 32000, 39000,47000,57000,69000,83000,99000,119000,143000,175000,210000,255000,310000,375000,450000,550000,675000,825000,1000000]
        if xp <= 1000 then
            @level = 1
            return
        end
        i=0
        while i < xp_req4lvl.length do
            if xp > xp_req4lvl[i] then
                i+=1
            elsif xp == xp_req4lvl[i] then
                @level = i+1
                return
            else
                @level = i
                return
        end
        ml = xp_req4lvl.length
        raise LevelingError.new(ml), "Level too high!", caller
        return
    end

    def initialize(personalInfo, training, race, chclass, feats, stuff, abilities, xp)
        @str, @con, @dex, @int, @wis, @cha = abilities
        @trainedSkills = training
        @characterClass = chclass
        @feats = feats
        @race = race
        #for featx in self.race["racialFeats"]:
        #    self.feats.append(featx)
        @equipment = stuff
        @background = personalInfo
        @xp =xp
        @actionPoints = 1
        @equippedArmor = nil
        @equippedShield = nil
        @armorProficiencies = []
        @shieldProficiencies = []
        @untrainedArmorEquipped = false
        @untrainedShieldEquipped = false
        @level = 0
        self.determineLevel
        rescue LevelingError => e
            puts "Character is over maximum level of " + e.get_max_lvl.to_s
            @level = 30
        end
        #self.calculateAbilityScores
        #self.calculateAbilityMods
        #self.calculateHP
        #self.determineProficiencies

        #@fortitudeSave = 10+(@level/2)
        #@reflexSave = 10+(@level/2)
        #@willSave = 10+(@level/2)
        #puts @level.to_s

        @healingSurgesUsed = 0
    end

    public
    def get_level
        return @level
    end      
end

class LevelingError < RuntimeError
    attr :maxLvl

    def initialize(ml)
        @maxLvl = ml
    end

    def get_max_lvl()
        return @maxLvl
    end
end

if __FILE__ == $0
    j = Player.new("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "[10,10,10,10,10,10]", "1250")
    puts j.get_level.to_s
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you missed one `end` keyword here:

```
while i < xp_req4lvl.length do
            if xp > xp_req4lvl[i] then
                i+=1
            elsif xp == xp_req4lvl[i] then
                @level = i+1
                return
            else
                @level = i
                return
        end # !> mismatched indentations at 'end' with 'while'
```

If you put one more `end` here,you wouldn't get the error.But you would get then another- `syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input` due to the below:

```
def initialize(personalInfo, training, race, chclass, feats, stuff, abilities, xp)
        @str, @con, @dex, @int, @wis, @cha = abilities
        @trainedSkills = training
        @characterClass = chclass
        @feats = feats
        @race = race
        #for featx in self.race["racialFeats"]:
        #    self.feats.append(featx)
        @equipment = stuff
        @background = personalInfo
        @xp =xp
        @actionPoints = 1
        @equippedArmor = nil
        @equippedShield = nil
        @armorProficiencies = []
        @shieldProficiencies = []
        @untrainedArmorEquipped = false
        @untrainedShieldEquipped = false
        @level = 0
        self.determineLevel
        rescue LevelingError => e
            puts "Character is over maximum level of " + e.get_max_lvl.to_s
            @level = 30
        end # !> mismatched indentations at 'end' with 'def'
```

You need to follow as below:

```
def method_name(..)
  begin
   # your code
  rescue
   # your codee
  end
end
```

But don't use `begin..rescue` inside the `#initialize` method.

Comment: Try what I said..he missed the `while` end,so `#initialize` method went into the `while` loop. If you put one `end` there,you will not get the argument error. try first then down-vote a correct answer..

Comment: ok, my bad, one up for you. Did not really get your answer, now I do.

Comment: @BeatRichartz thanks for coming up... :) I tried the code and then answered..But credit goes to my editor which clearly marked the error point,when i pressed `ctrl+X`.. :)